# Stop formData string from being converted to a date string representation

Tags: string, date, .net-core, type-conversion, isodate

This one is being hard to uncover. We have a .NET Core 2.2 app in which we have a form with many fields and a field for the user to attach some file.

Problem: one specific field `CaqhNumber` has a min and max length = 8.

When the user types in a value for example `20200706` the value that get's sent to the server is a date string representation of this value. So on the server side we get:

```
07/06/2020
```

Basically it thinks this specific field is an [ISO date](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).

[image: ![Do]

How can one stop this from happening? We just want to get the string on the server side the way it was entered on the UI side. It's not a date. It's plain string in both sides.

Something tells me this is related to the .NET Core configs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guess what... there was a piece of code behind the curtains messing up with the value:

```
const isValidDate = moment(
        value,
        moment.ISO_8601,
        true
    ).isValid();

    if (isValidDate) {
        formData.append(
            key,
            moment(value).format('MM/DD/YYYY')
        );
```

The fix:

```
if (value instanceof Date) {
    formData.append(key, moment(value).format('MM/DD/YYYY'));
```